# How to send different currency to PayPal

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, paypal, currency-rates

I am not sure if this is a Magento or a PayPal setup, but here is my problem:

Our Magento 1.9.2.4 has the base currency is US Dollar. All my products have US Dollar price. I also have multiple websites in my Magento for different countries. When someone access from a different country (Canada, for example), the user will see the prices in Canadian Dollar.

I am doing that using Magento Conversion Rate and setting my Canadian website to use Canadian Dollar as default currency. So the product is still in US Dollar but Magento converts it to show in the frontend as Canadian Dollar.

The problem is, when the user selects PayPal to make the purchase, Magento is sending the price to PayPal in US Dollar, and then PayPal will convert it to Canadian Dollar (using a different conversion rate than ours).

Is there a way to fix that (send the amount in Canadian Dollar to PayPal)? Right now we have a discount in our conversion rate and the user is "paying more" because PayPal is using their own rates.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this tutorial http://chandreshrana.blogspot.in/2014/07/inr-currency-convert-issue-with-paypal.html

If you using multiple currency, you can try this tutorial : http://www.magentostack.com/magento-multicurrency-support-for-paypal/

Comment: Thank you @H_Parekh, I will check the links and post here what I found

Comment: I realized that I was missing some information and this was the wrong question to my problem. However, your answer solves the problem of currencies not supported by PayPal, so I am accepting it. I also posted a new question with more information for my real problem here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151568/how-do-i-use-multiple-currencies-for-payments

Comment: In my case, my currencies are already supported by PayPal but Magento is not sending the currency that I want to be sent...

Answer (score 0):

This extension can help you send the currency your customer chooses instead of Base Currency to Paypal: https://meetanshi.com/magento-paypal-multi-currency.html