# How to use paypal for other currency in Magento2

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, paypal, currency

I have magento2 with base currency NPR I want to use Paypal as another payment option. where as papal doesn't support NPR i want to pay it in droller.

for that I have added "NPR" in  **$_supportedCurrencyCodes** variable in `vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Config.php`

add logic for sending currency code "USD" instead of "NPR" and change amount to USD in `vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php` in "start" function while checkout it give me error for Paypal doesn't support for shipping to Nepal.
Is their any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 8):

**Here is the example of use AED currency in PayPal. You can use same for other currencies.**

Follow this step to support other currencies in paypal:

**1) Override `Config.php` and `Nvp.php`**

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Paypal\Model\Config" type="{Vendor}\{Module}\Model\Magento\Paypal\Config" />
    <preference for="Magento\Paypal\Model\Api\Nvp" type="{Vendor}\{Module}\Model\Magento\Paypal\Api\Nvp" />
</config>
```

**2) Add your currency in `$_supportedCurrencyCodes`**

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/Model/Magento/Paypal/Config

```
protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = [
    'AUD',
    'CAD',
    'CZK',
    'DKK',
    'EUR',
    'HKD',
    'HUF',
    'ILS',
    'JPY',
    'MXN',
    'NOK',
    'NZD',
    'PLN',
    'GBP',
    'RUB',
    'SGD',
    'SEK',
    'CHF',
    'TWD',
    'THB',
    'USD',
    'AED', // Add currency
];
```

**3) Now convert currency amount to USD amount in API request**

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/Model/Magento/Paypal/Api/Nvp.php

Inject `\Magento\Directory\Helper\Data` class for convert currency rate

Approx after line: 1175

```
//print_r($request);

if ($request["METHOD"] == "SetExpressCheckout" || $request["METHOD"] == "DoExpressCheckoutPayment")
{
    if($request['CURRENCYCODE'] == "AED") {

        $payAmt = $request['AMT'];
        $payShippingAmt = $request['SHIPPINGAMT'];
        $payItemAmt = $request['ITEMAMT'];
        $payTaxAmt = $request['TAXAMT'];
        $conAmt = round($this->_currencyHelper->currencyConvert($payAmt, "AED", "USD"), 2);
        $conShippingAmt = round($this->_currencyHelper->currencyConvert($payShippingAmt, "AED", "USD"), 2);
        $conItemAmt = round($this->_currencyHelper->currencyConvert($payItemAmt, "AED", "USD"), 2);
        $conTaxAmt = round($this->_currencyHelper->currencyConvert($payTaxAmt, "AED", "USD"), 2);

        //set converted USD amount to request api

        $request['CURRENCYCODE'] = "USD";
        $request['AMT'] = $conAmt;
        $request['SHIPPINGAMT'] = $conShippingAmt;
        $request['ITEMAMT'] = $conItemAmt;
        $request['TAXAMT'] = $conTaxAmt;
    }
}
```

**Note: set Transfer Cart Line Items to No From**

> Store->Configuration->Sales->PaymentMethod->Paypal->Configure->Advanced Settings

To pass only order, shipping and tax amount

If you set yes from this config setting. Magento passes all cart item amount to PayPal request and you have to change the logic of converting price.

Comment: In Magento2.2.4 EE I have edited above files and configured as defined by you. Now on checkout page at order placing time I am getting that message

"PayPal gateway has rejected request. Receiving country does not support the transaction currency (#10605: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details)."

Please help me what can I do to resolve it. Merchant country = UAE and default currency = AED.

Comment: @Prince Patel Have you tried and tested your solution?

Comment: @Nafisa My 90% answers in MSE is tested.

Comment: @PrincePatel How can i override the class in app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/Model/Magento/Paypal/Config and app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/Model/Magento/Paypal/Api/Nvp.php.
Can you give me full code

Comment: @PrincePatel This is not working for me. please help

Comment: I have the same issue with another payment gateway . So is there is any setup in magneto that once we send to payment gateway change the currency code to AED

Comment: could you please check this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316173/change-currency-once-we-send-the-payment-to-payment-gateway

Answer (score 2):

I've created a simple M2 module to handle this. You can use it
https://github.com/zamoroka/Magento-2-Paypal-All-Currencies-extension

Comment: Thanks, After I installed your extension, Paypal show up, But I have an issue "PayPal gateway has rejected request. Order total is invalid (#10401: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details)." Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Hi @DavidDuong This module was developed 3 years ago just for fun. Unfortunately, I don't have time currently to maintain it but feel free to create an issue in github repo or even fix it, I'll review PR and approve it if there is a good fix :)

Comment: I have fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My base currency is INR and PayPal currency set to USD. On purchasing INR as the base it's working but on switching the currency to USD from frontend currency switcher. Paypal rejects with an error message.Do you have any idea to solve this.
My requirement is if the current active currency is USD no need to convert.