# Change currency once we send the payment to payment gateway

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-gateway, currency

in my website i have mainly USD and AED currency . Base currency is USD . Recently i integrate a payment gate way to my website . But that payment gateway only accept AED Currency .

So is there any way when sending to payment gateway we can change the currency to AED . Please help .

Comment: as far as i understand you can change the base currency to AED to let the gateway handle it