# How to use AED currency in PAYPAL for other currency in Magento2

Tags: magento2, paypal, paypal-express, currency, multicurrency

I have a magento2 store with base currency AED. Paypal doesn't support AED. How to make support for this currency in Magento 2 for Paypal.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176186/how-to-use-paypal-for-other-currency-in-magento2  This will be helpfull for you

Comment: I tried this but no luck.